# How to implement accordion in angular2 and typescript

Tags: css, typescript, angular, angular-ui-bootstrap, accordion

I am creating list of div dynamically.I want the content of only fist
div will display by default.But when user click on second div then
content of second should be display and the content of first is hide.And so on with third and forth div.

This is like accordion.Here is my code

```
<div class="content-area">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="accordian">
        <div class="errors-cont" *ngFor="#error of errors">
            <div class="acc-header active" (click)="onClick()">
                <div class="image"><img src="image2/nike.png"></div>
                <div class="text">
                <div class="title">Nike<span>20-04-2016,  03:10 PM</span></div>
                <p>{{error.title}}</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="acc-desc" [class.hide]="isSpecial">
                <div class="image"></div>
                <div class="text">
                <p>{{error.desc}}</p>
                <div class="acc-block">
                    <div class="title">ERROR TYPE asdf</div>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit ame</p>
                </div>
                <div class="acc-block">
                    <div class="title">REASON</div>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit ame</p>
                </div>
                <div class="acc-block">
                    <div class="btns">
                    <input name="" type="button" value="RESOLVE" class="transparent">
                    <input name="" type="button" value="IGNORE" class="green">
                    </div>
                </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div><!-- end or ngFor loop -->     
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {HeroService} from './error.service';

import { ROUTER_DIRECTIVES } from '@angular/router';
import {CORE_DIRECTIVES} from '@angular/common';
import {DROPDOWN_DIRECTIVES} from 'ng2-bootstrap/ng2-bootstrap';

@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: 'errors-view',
    templateUrl: 'errors-view.html',
    providers: [HeroService],
    styleUrls: ['errors.css'],
    directives: [DROPDOWN_DIRECTIVES, CORE_DIRECTIVES, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES]
})

export class ErrorsViewComponent {

    errors:string[] = [];
    isClose = true;
    isActive= false;
    isSpecial= false;

    //disValue = true
    constructor(private heroService:HeroService) {
        heroService.loadItems()
            .subscribe(data => this.errors = data);
        console.log('erros will be shown in this page');
    }

    togglePopover() {
        this.isClose = !this.isClose;
    }

    onClick(){
        this.isActive = true;
        this.isSpecial = true;
        //this.disValue = false;
        console.log("active false");

        //var x = document.getElementsByClassName("acc-header");

            console.log(x.length);
        // for (var i=0; i < x.length; i++) {
        //  x[i].onclick = function() {deleteIt(this)}

        // }



    }
}
```

Comment: could you please provide plunker of your code, or you can adopt my method read below my answer as alternate

Comment: I have edited my code please see that.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

PS:- as Alternate

If you want to use Accordion then why not to use this ?

http://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/accordion

PrimeNg provides us all the functionaly needed you just have to add this

```
import {Accordion} from 'primeng/primeng';
import {AccordionTab} from 'primeng/primeng';
```

Comment: I seen that.But in my case i created div dynamically usng *ngFor and each div has same class.

Answer (score 2):

Use the index to add the 'active' class if it's the first one.

```
*ngFor="#error of errors; let i=index"

div class="acc-header" [class.active]="i == 0" (click)="onClick(i)"
```

Comment: This needs another condition on the onClick to close the current `active` class but definitely helped me create idea to make this happen without writing another component. Thanks